# forge.topbar.setTint(); Changing the color of the apps topbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, trigger.io

This is probably a very silly question but i am stuck on this problem.
I am currently using trigger.io to develop and iphone app there is a JS function that allows you to change the color of the top bar but i cannot seem to make it work.

here is the documentation:

https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/modules/topbar.html#forgetopbarsettintcolor-success-error

```
forge.topbar.setTint(color, success, error)
```

a few things i have tried

```
forge.topbar.setTint({color:[255,0,0,50]});
forge.topbar.setTint(color:[255,0,0,50]);

forge.topbar.setTint(array(255,0,0,50));
```

Comment: Did you try to pass `success` and `error` callbacks too, to see what's happening?

Comment: Im not sure how i would go about that. I am not so good at javascript unfortunately

Comment: Try with `forge.topbar.setTint([255,0,0,50], function() {console.log('Success!');}, function(content) {console.log('Error:'+content);});` and open your browser console to see output.

Comment: manuelpedrera - It worked! Thank you so much for the help. Looks like i was trying to define it wrong.

forge.topbar.setTint([255,0,0,50]);

That seems to change the color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comments, the correct way to call setTint with that RGBA color would be:

```
forge.topbar.setTint([255,0,0,50], function() {
    console.log('Success!');
}, function(content) {
    console.log('Error:'+content);
});
```